# continuity of function at x = 2 and x = -1

Tags: limits, continuity

There is a function (x-2)/($x^2 - x - 2)$.

I need to check its continuity at 2 points x = 2 and x = -1 using method of left hand and right hand limit. I am not sure how to calculate the function's left hand and right hand limit separately.

Please help me out here.

Thanks,

Comment: Hint: What is your definition of continuity? Your book should give one. You need to verify that three separate things are equal to verify continuity: two limits and a value of the function. If you find that any of the three aren't equal, you are done and have discontinuity.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. One may first observe that
$$
\frac{x-2}{x^2-x-2}=\frac{(x-2)}{(x-2)(x+1)}=\frac1{x+1}, \quad x \neq -1,\,x \neq 2.
$$ Then the latter expression is easier to evaluate as $x \to -1^-$, $x \to -1^+$ as $x \to 2$.

Comment: ...$x\ne -1$. . ...

Comment: Yes, it is written: $x \neq-1$, $x \neq 2$.

Comment: @olivier so, both left hand and right hand limit for x = 1 are equal = 1/2, right? and same goes for x = 2. right?

Comment: @user2409011 Exactly. But do you mean $x=\color{red}{-}1$?

Comment: Ohh, my bad. yes x = -1, so at x = -1 function is touching infinity which means limit does not exist and hence discontinuous. Right?

Comment: Yes, this is right.

Comment: @user2409011 Are you Ok with My answer? Thanks.